# Linq with multiple contains

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

In our UI the users can free text a search that is applied to a number of fields.

```
            q = q.Where(p => p.Account.Contains(query)
                             || p.AccountName.Contains(query)
                             || p.AccountAKA.Contains(query)
                             || p.AccountRef.Contains(query));
```

This translates into SQL. Is there a more optimal way to querying, as this is slow.

There are about 20,000 rows. Database disk size doesn't matter, memory usage does.

Comment: The problem is that `LIKE %query%` is not efficient enough. The problem can solve indexing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2009/11/30/index-usage-by-like-operator-query-tuning.aspx

Comment: The only solution I see to solve that is to create your own indexation table (indexing all p.Account[x..y] strings). But it requires a lot of memory.
How many rows do you have in the database?

Comment: When the user type the query, does it queries the database synchronously or asynchronously? Because improving the speed of the query seems quite difficult. So, you may work on the user experience itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all these are text fields each of the values translates to `Account LIKE '%'+ query+ '%'`. All queries with wildcards on both sides will be slow, unfortunately there is not too much that can be done.

Maybe it is possible to use `StartsWith()` instead of `Contains()`? This would translate to `LIKE query + '%' which is generally much faster?

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to change your data model and use a `Description` column that has ALL the account name info in it so you can do your query against a single column.  Updates to the record result in an update to this Description column.

Comment: Oh, I agree. But sometimes constraints don't allow for it :(